# Rigid body animation problems (coin pusher animation)

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

Im trying to make a coin pusher animation with rigid bodies in Blender.

I have a few problems.

- The 5 coins on the 'pusher' itself dont fall down. They stay on the same level. They dont join and interact with the other coins.[image]
- Some coins just fly away randomly.[image]

I have tried different shape collision objects. Increased the steps per second and solver iternations in the Rigid body world. Made sure al my normals are pointing in the right directions.

Hope anyone can help me!

Thanks x

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, 
is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) 
and is [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing)

Comment: Have you 'Applied Scale' to each of your objects? Also, ensure the Origin of each is set to the object's centre of mass.

Answer (score 3):

I've only done 4 coins here.  See if these physics settings work for you.
You can see those in the Blend file below.
Make sure to check those for the slide and pusher also.

[image]

You'll notice that all coins have much the same settings, except Coin 1. (leftmost)   Varying those on individual coins will obviously affect their behavior and can be used to break up their similarity if felt necessary.

e.g. Coin 1's "Rotation Damping" is wound down to zero at frame 1 and stays that way to help it flip over when it falls. Once it has rolled over, the value is rapidly increased (keyframed) to 1.00 to settle it down.

There's not a lot more to tell you, except perhaps the significance of the coins' "Shape" being set to 'Cylinder' instead of mesh.  This improved coin-like behavior.

The  "Collision Margin" was set to 0.002 but with it shaded out, I don't think it matters.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the big(the one on the bottom) mesh's "shape" is coming from mesh, not convex hull:
[image]

I've posted the blend if it may be of any help:

[image]